# jqGrid: addRowData adds an empty row even when data is provided

Tags: jqgrid

I have 2 jqGrids and when I click on a row in the first jqGrid, I need to add that row to the 2nd jqGrid and delete it from the first grid but when I click on the row, an empty row gets added to the 2nd grid although I see the data in firebug. I have the following code in onSelectRow of first grid:

```js
var sourceGrid = jQuery('#admin-chooser-source-'+randomId);;
var destGrid = jQuery('#admin-chooser-dest-'+randomId);
var data = sourceGrid.getRowData(id);
console.log('data is ',data);
var success = destGrid.addRowData('admin-chooser-dest-row-'+id, data, 'last');
console.log('success ',success);
sourceGrid.delRowData(id);
```

Console prints:
data is
    Object>
    allAvailPrinters: "Laboratory"

success  true

Comment: If `name` property in the first grid are not the same as in the second grid you can have the effects which you describe. So you should provide the code which defines both jqGrid and the test data for the first one.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I wasn't using the same 'name' attr in both the grids. Thanks.